# How to get selected text from SelectableText widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using SelectableText widget to make Text selectable. But I don't know how to get the selected text and log it to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `ToolbarOptions` inside your `SelectableText` with `copy: true` and then read the data from the clipboard.

```
SelectableText(
  'your text',
  toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(copy: true)
);
```

Here is an answered question about the clipboard:
[Flutter can't read from Clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392726/flutter-cant-read-from-clipboard)

Edits: Clean up the answer and add more info.

Comment: Thanks  @Andrei Caisim. Is there any way to make this by default...i mean when user tap on the text, instead of poping copy button, by default it should copy.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, as I cannot see any controller or listener that listens to how much of the text is selected.