# How to select a word or multiple words from a sentence in a container and perform an action with the chosen word in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to select a word or multiple words from a sentence 
for eg; Tom had a red hat.

I wanted to choose a hat or red or any of the other words from the sentence and perform an action on the chosen word. I can't seem to understand how i would be able to do that. I have tried it by assigning each word a button. But I wanted to use selectable text for this because I wanted to also choose multiple words of the sentence for example 'red hat' or tom had a''

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832123/get-selected-text-from-textview

Comment: @AjayKS This is for android i presume

Comment: so you are using `SelectableText("Lorem ipsum...")` ?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392726/flutter-cant-read-from-clipboard @ZahidAhmed

Comment: @pskink i tried using SelectableText() however it does not return to you, the text you have chosen.

Comment: use `Clipboard` class then

Comment: You cant pass the word selected to the clipboard class.. @pskink

Comment: so what would be `SelectableText` class useful for? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57911047/2252830

Comment: SelectableText only allows you to copy, paste, cut and select all text. I want to customize these toolbar options which cannot be done for SelectableText

Comment: so you have to write your custom `StatelessWidget`

Comment: Yeah, was wondering if anyone had done it before and could help me out...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'word_selectable_text 0.2.0' package.

```
Container(
        padding:  EdgeInsets.all(40),
        width:  double.infinity,
        child:  WordSelectableText(
            selectable:  true,
            highlight:  true,
            text:'Tom had a red hat',
            onWordTapped: (word, index) {
            print(word);},
            style:  TextStyle(fontSize:  20)
    )),
```